# Load video file with PHP

Tags: php, video, load

http://www.videodorm.org/get_video.php?video=155676
I had a question about the link above. If you view the source their is absolutly NO html. I was wondering how they load a video file with just php. I know that the video id in the url has something to do with it, but could someone explain to me how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side script which means it can run processes, download files or initiate header redirections without outputting any HTML.

There is actually HTML however it is all printed or echoes using PHP commands (http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Depending on the browser you can view the created DOM source using developer tools.  In Firefox you can bring this up with Ctrl+Shift+I